# Start redis worker automatically

Tags: redis, celery, stackexchange.redis, celery-task

Am using celery with redis its working fine but problem is to start worker have to give manually.Is there any way to start **'Redis woker'** automatically without doing manually

Answer (score 0):

There is a [whole section in the Celery documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html) about it.